# Перемещение элементов ListView в WinForms

Tags: c#, drag-n-drop, winforms, listview

Здравствуйте, пытаюсь сделать перемещение элементов между ListView. Как сделать так, что бы элементы перемещались на ту позицию где их отпустили, а не в конец списка. Вот код.

```
private void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
     var listView = sender as ListView;
     var items = e.Data.GetData ("System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedListViewItemCollection") as ListView.SelectedListViewItemCollection;
     ListViewItem SelectedItem = GetItemFromPoint(listView, Cursor.Position);
     foreach (ListViewItem item in items)
     {
          item.ListView.Items.Remove(item);
          if (SelectedItem != null)
               { listView.Items.Insert(SelectedItem.Index, item);}
          else
               { listView.Items.Add(item); }
     }
}

private void listView1_ItemDrag(object sender, ItemDragEventArgs e)
{
     var listView = sender as ListView;
     listView.DoDragDrop(listView.SelectedItems, DragDropEffects.Move);
}

private void listView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
      var listView = sender as ListView;
      if (e.Data.GetDataPresent ("System.Windows.Forms.ListView+SelectedListViewItemCollection") && e.AllowedEffect == DragDropEffects.Move)
                e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Move;
}

private ListViewItem GetItemFromPoint(ListView listView, Point mousePosition)
{
      Point localPoint = listView.PointToClient(mousePosition);
      return listView.GetItemAt(localPoint.X, localPoint.Y);
}
```

Comment: @Denis-ProfIT, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: Спасибо, отформатировал.

Comment: Вопрос решен, если кому интересно, то решение здесь http://www.gotdotnet.ru/forums/3/144881/

Answer (score 1):

думаю выходом будет проиндексировать записи в списках и при переносе элемента вы получаете индекс элемента в списке, вот код ваш же:

```
private ListViewItem GetItemFromPoint(ListView listView, Point mousePosition)
{
      Point localPoint = listView.PointToClient(mousePosition);
      return listView.GetItemAt(localPoint.X, localPoint.Y);
}
```

а после назначаете новому элементу следующий индекс, а индексы после обновляете. Сортировка по индексу в списке поставит все на места.